# Android ListView with attached headerview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a weird pronlem with a custom `ListFragment` into my android app. I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my `listView` which is handled by a `LoaderManager` and besides this i also have a `headerView` attached:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getListView().getHeaderViewsCount() <= 0 && headerView != null)

        getListView().addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

            if (listAdapter == null)
    listAdapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.label1,
            (CategoryModel) getArguments().getParcelable(MODEL_KEY));
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    setListShown(false);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

     }



    private final static class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ICatalogModel> {
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final CategoryModel parentModel;

        private CustomArrayFilter filter;

        public DataAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId,
                CategoryModel parentModel) {
            super(c, textViewResourceId);
            this.parentModel = parentModel;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }



        public ArrayList<ICatalogModel> getData() {
            return originalValues;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ItemHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rooms_list_row, parent, false);
                holder = new ItemHolder();
                holder.nameField = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label1);
                v.setTag(holder);
            }

            holder = (ItemHolder) v.getTag();

            final ICatalogModel model = getItem(position);
            holder.nameField.setText(model.getName());
            return v;
        }

        public void addAllSupport(ArrayList<ICatalogModel> data) {
            for (ICatalogModel p : data) {
                add(p);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

On the `onLoaderReset` method i am trying to clear adapter's data by calling `myAdapter.clear()` but a weird `IndexOutOfBounds` exception is thrown in the android `HeaderViewListAdapter` class at line 126:

```
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ICatalogModel>> arg0) {
    if (listAdapter != null) {
            ((DataAdapter) listAdapter).clear();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ICatalogModel>> arg0,
        ArrayList<ICatalogModel> arg1) {

    if (listAdapter != null) {
        ((DataAdapter) listAdapter).clear();
        if (CokConstants.SUPPORTS_HONEYCOMB) {
            ((DataAdapter) listAdapter).addAll(arg1);
        } else {
            ((DataAdapter) listAdapter).addAllSupport(arg1);
        }
        ((DataAdapter) listAdapter).setOriginalValues(arg1);
    }
    if (isResumed())
        setListShown(true);
    else
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
}
```

I figured it out that the problem was somehow related with the fact that i am not removing the `headerView` on the `onDestroyView` method...i did that...no more exception...but now another problem...whenever i go back to that fragment from backstack ...the list is not visible anymore eventhough the data is added correctly in the adapter.
Has anyone encountered this problem before ?

Comment: To help you, we need to see some relevant code. I also recommend formatting your question- right now it is just a wall of text, making it very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add a header or a footer view to your `ListView`; the adapter you set to it, is wrapped into `WrapperListAdapter`. You must check instance of the adapter.

```
DataAdapter myExistingAdapter = null;
if(listAdapter instanceof WrapperListAdapter) {
    myExistingAdapter = (DataAdapter)((WrapperListAdapter)listAdapter).getWrappedAdapter();
} else if (listAdapter instanceof DataAdapter) {
    myExistingAdapter = (DataAdapter)listAdapter;
}
```

> [android.widget.WrapperListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/WrapperListAdapter.html) 
>   Known Indirect Subclasses
>   HeaderViewListAdapter

Comment: True...and yes seems the right thing to do now...I was driving in circles around the solution for hours but now seems so damn obvious...calling just clear() on the adapter it will call the clear() method on the WrappedListAdapter in my case and not on the DataAdapter as I needed...thanks man !!